# How to fix [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: python, docker, networking, oauth-2.0, docker-compose

I am setting up an oauth2 server using the authlib (0.11) library. I already created the Oauth2Session and received the authorization code grant. Now I have to fetch_access_token(...), but I am receiving a [Errno 111] Connection refused while trying to communicate with the access_token_url. I am using docker compose, and have linked both with a bridge. I am also using port mapping to access the localhost from the host. (macOS)

I already tried netcat on the localhost and the specific link and sending GET / HTTP/1.1. It worked.
I have already checked port forwarding and it is set to true (=1)
I tried setting the name of the host link (127.0.0.1) as the docker compose name (backend)

```py
access_token_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:50000/oauth/token'
# tried 'http://backend:50000/oauth/token', 'http://localhost:50000/oauth/token'
token = sessionOauth.fetch_access_token(access_token_url, authorization_response=authorization_response)
```

```py
# the part that concerns the question
backend:
    build: .

    ports:
      - "50000:5000"
    environment:
      - AUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT=true
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
    networks:
      - db
      - front_back

vuejs:
    build: ../x/
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - front_back
networks:
    main:
      driver: bridge
    db:
      driver: bridge
    front_back:
      driver: bridge
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2311, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1834, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1737, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 36, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1832, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1818, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_cors/decorator.py", line 128, in wrapped_function
    resp = make_response(f(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/var/app/app/routes.py", line 325, in testing3
    token = sessionOauth.fetch_access_token(access_token_url, authorization_response=authorization_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/authlib/client/oauth2_session.py", line 102, in fetch_access_token
    return self.fetch_token(url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/authlib/oauth2/client.py", line 177, in fetch_token
    headers=headers, **session_kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/authlib/oauth2/client.py", line 185, in _fetch_token
    auth=auth, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 581, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/authlib/client/oauth2_session.py", line 110, in request
    method, url, auth=auth, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=50000): Max retries exceeded with url: /oauth/token (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fc872466198>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

Comment: Add your compose file.

Comment: Please check edit

Comment: 'Connection refused' means that nothing was listening at the IP:port you tried to connect to. So either the IP:port wasn't correct or you didn't start the server.

Comment: As I already mentioned, I tried netcat to same ip / port and it connected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is:

use the name of the container, in my case backend, and then use the original port not the exposed one, in my case 5000.

```
access_token_url = 'http://backend:5000/oauth/token'
```

Comment: I got an errno 111 Connection refused when connecting one containerised backend service to another containerised backend service and this answer solved the error. It makes sense when you think of it, since both apps are running in docker containers.